# Unable to remove device in windows 11 home edition

Tags: windows

As title. Need help removing the Unknown devices.
[image]
[image]

Right-clicking remove devices results in "Remove failed".

Comment: You can't remove the device because it's `Unavailable` and is not actually connected to your machine, you likely have network discovery enabled, which means it will discover devices on your network.  Do you have network discovery enabled?  You should [edit] your question to include that vital information.  I also assume you have an `Anker Soundcore Boost Bluetooth` audio device connected to your device?  **You can also remove the device, in device manager, if you show hidden devices and uninstall the device under Bluetooth devices.**

Comment: It was a bluetooth speaker but I no longer have it. It should therefore be deletable from the list. I have manually removed all the SoundCore related drivers from "Device Manager", also deleted some registry values, but I still can't make it disappear.

Comment: Which keys did you remove? Can you provide a screenshot of the Device Manager with hidden devices enabled?  You failed to mention you already tried that. You have clearly missed a key and/or something is being discovered.  Have you tried disabling network discovery to see if that will clear the device?